# can access central administration but unable to access newly created site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site-collection, windows-7

I was able to install SP 2010 on my Windows 7 64 bit machine using [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

I am now able to access the SharePoint Central Administration at port 24469.
Something like:

```
http://mymachinename:24469/_admin/createsite.aspx
```

I was able to create a new site collection and but am unable to access it. New site collection is at port 80.

```
http://mymachinename:80/sites/mynewsite
```

I've done this [workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) to no avail. I've also added

```
http://mymachinename:80
```

to the list of intranet sites. Did not work either.

Note that I am accessing the site from the server itself.

The error being returned is a 'Webpage not available' message.

Comment: what error you are getting? did you created the root level site collection i.e http://mymachinename:80, if you browse this then what happen? Please share the error details

Comment: the site was created at root level. when i browse the mymachinename:80, i get Webpage not available

Answer (score 0):

You could check "Central Administration -> Site Collection -> Quotas and Locks" and check that your site collection isn't in a "no access" state. Source along with other conversations here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/appvirtualization/en-US/ebcd6e59-c429-4710-9ab2-00e962d55795/sharepoint-2010-not-able-to-access-site-collection-page-not-found

If you get a 404 you should check here: [Going to a Site Collection homepage gives a 404](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26568/going-to-a-site-collection-homepage-gives-a-404)

In the event you are getting an access denied -type of error, check here: http://www.brainlitter.com/2011/08/30/resolution-for-site-collection-admins-in-new-site-collection-get-access-denied/

I hope this helps at least a little bit! :-)

Comment: thanks for sharing but none of these work either. I'm not getting a 404 error but rather a 'Site not available' error

Comment: Ok sorry to hear that! I'll let you know if I come up with any other possible solutions.. EDIT: Just thought that does it require https to be used in the URL?